Slice-ribbon conjecture in other 3-manifolds
There is some notion of what it means for a knot $K\hookrightarrow M$ to be "slice." In particular, we may ask, for example, that there is a topologically embedded disk in $M\times[0,1]$ whose boundary lies on $M\times\{0\}$ and is $K$. It's less clear to me if there's also an analogous notion of "ribbon." Of course, we would need to pick a particular Morse function, but is there a canonical such for a manifold $M$? Or does it not really matter? Or is this not a particularly useful idea?
More generally, I am curious if anyone knots of a way in which slice-ness of knots in general manifolds can be applied to studying the slice-ribbon conjecture (either generalizations thereof or the $S^3$ version).

One may still ask for the disk to be “ribbon” in $M\times [0,1]$ in the sense that the projection of $M×[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ is a Morse function when restricted to the disk with only index 1 and 2 critical points. Assuming the index $2$ critical points are higher than the index 1 critical points (which one may assume by general position), running the movie backwards one sees an unlink in the manifold, then a bunch of bands connecting these unlink components to give a knot. Taking disks bounding the unknotted components of the unlink, one sees a disk in the manifold with only ribbon singularities as in the $S^3$ case. One may also reconstruct the Morse function from such a ribbon disk just like the classical case.
If the knot is slice in $M×[0,1]$, then its lift to the universal cover $\tilde{M}×[0,1] ⊂ S^3×[0,1]$ will also be slice (see the question). Hence the slice-ribbon conjecture would imply that the lift of the knot to the universal cover will be ribbon. However, it is not clear to me if $K$ will be ribbon in $M$. So it seems like the ribbon-slice conjecture might be stronger for knots in general 3-manifolds.
